# Fluid trainer, repair leak?

Tags: repair, trainer

I have a Travel Trac (Performance Bicycle) Century V fluid trainer, vintage c. 2005, that I've pressed into heavy-duty service during the pandemic.

It's been working well these past months, but seems to have developed a leak recently.

Is it reasonable to try to repair the leak? I found a video where a guy fixed his JetBlack fluid trainer by just replacing an O-ring.

Rather than trying to fix it myself, I'd like to hand off the task to a professional. Is there a shop in the US (even better, the Bay Area) that's experienced with this repair?

I'd hate to trash the otherwise-fine trainer for a failed $1 part.

Comment: Have you opened it to investigate?  Photos of the site of the leak might help.  Its very likely out of warranty now so no harm in trying to fix it yourself.

Comment: O-rings, if one is at fault, are standardized parts.